# Can't reach docker port actix web build

Tags: docker

I have an app based on actix web and I'm trying to containerize it. When I run the build locally it works fine, but when I built it through docker, the app starts fine and binds to local docker port, but is not accessible from host.

How I'm running the container:

```
docker run -p 80:80 myapp
```

Dockerfile (abreviated):

```
[...] // Builds binaries
FROM debian:buster-slim
COPY --from=server-builder /usr/src/myapp/target/release/myapp /usr/bin
COPY --from=frontend-builder /usr/src/frontend/dist /static
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["myapp"]
```

I don't have any other services running on port 80, and I've tried using different host ports. It's not something wrong with my binary since it runs fine locally and logs show it runs fine in docker. It's not a miscofiguration of the /static directory since server logs connections (even in production builds) and it's not reaching the server when in docker.

Here are network settings when running `docker inspect`

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "f7fe576d1f3c1612bb5afa94c3c360a12b0c0d464881835a0347fcadad228343",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f7fe576d1f3c",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "b5939e954990ef71f4b69929beaf9af8f0b28f7fa9ee32363a9aefdd2f49107b",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "3eefce33be199f43e6aaa5866606a9a2da0daf25e662b510a18ed1820fb4d1d9",
                    "EndpointID": "b5939e954990ef71f4b69929beaf9af8f0b28f7fa9ee32363a9aefdd2f49107b",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Attaching a bash to the container and running `curl localhost:80` gets a succesfull reply from the server. I've tried running other apps which expose ports and they do work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Figured it out. First of all, the comand line argument is hostport:containerport and not the other way around.

Second, server was only acepting localhost connections. Will see what's up with actix. A good way to debug that is using `--network host` argument with `docker run`